# SQL query to get the rows count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table contain 3 columns *sID*, *sUID*, *parentSUID* with data like this:

```
 *sID*  |  *sUID*  |   *parentSUID*
----------------------------------
  sID1  |   sUID1  |     null
  sID1  |   sUID2  |     null
  sID1  |   sUID3  |    psUID2
  sID1  |   sUID4  |    psUID2
  sID2  |   sUID5  |     null
  sID2  |   sUID6  |    psUID5
```

I want to get all the sUID that doesn't has a parent and the count of children for each one, the result should be like this.

```
 *sID*  |  *sUID*  |    *count*
----------------------------------
  sID1  |   sUID1  |     0
  sID1  |   sUID2  |     2
  sID2  |   sUID5  |     1
```

I wrote a query but its give me the result without the count column, i don't know how to manage this.

Comment: what is the query you wrote?

Comment: What is the query you have tried? Is the `parentSUID` really starting with `p`?

Comment: SELECT  sID, sUID, parentSUID FROM a189 WHERE parentSUID IS NULL; This without the count. each time i wrote with the count it didn't get right values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.sID, p.sUID, count(c.sUID)
FROM a189 p left outer join a189 c on 'p' + p.sUID =  c.ParentSUID
where p.ParentSUID is null
group by p.sID, p.sUID
```

Besides using group by, sub query is another choice.

```
SELECT p.sID, p.sUID, (select count(1) FROM a189 c where 'p' + p.sUID = c.ParentSUID)
FROM a189 p
where p.ParentSUID is null
```

Result:

```
sID     sUID    Count
sID1    sUID1   0
sID1    sUID2   2
sID2    sUID5   1
```

Comment: it's one table that i am dealing with not two table.

Comment: Did you try these queries? none of them work for me - the first one returns different values than required, the second one returns an ORA-00936 missing expression. Also note that identified like "parent" and "child" are reserved words and should not be used.

Comment: TIP: You can put [] around column and table names if they are reserved words or someone decided it's a good idea to put a space somewhere in the name.

Comment: @JuannStrauss, in Oracle DB you use `"` `"` for that. But still this is bad practice

Comment: @JuannStrauss actually it's not "sid" but i wrote it like this to make it easy to read, in my code it's SPAN_UUID, anyway i tried the both of the queries, non of them work, and i want to get the data from one table not two tables

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss, second query works - just needs some small fixes. see here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/afc1e/11

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss Sorry that I'm using SQL Server and not test it. Please see my updated answer, I tested and both work.

Comment: @A.B.Cade i already fix it but it gives me wrong values,the first one always gives all the sUID with count 0, and the second one gives one sUID and count 18 which is weird, because non of the rows had 18 child, i don't know what 18 is exactly.

Comment: @Teddy thanks for your help :), but it's always give me this error: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss your field type is int or varchar? If int, remove the "'p' +"

Comment: count(*), not count(1) please.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Why count(*)? the result is same. I'm testing in SQL Server. Will it be different with Oracle?

Comment: The ANSI syntax is count(*), and anything else looks suspiciously like a trick that improves on it, which it doesn't

Comment: @DavidAldridge Oh it's first time I heard this. Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes one inherits an existing project with "bad practices".